# Iframe video change not working in ipad using jquery

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, iframe

I have three buttons and on click each of them the video which is in another div will change.

It's working fine in desktop but not in ipad.

My code is

```
$('.whitegreenround').click(function(){
   var URL = $(this).attr('data-url');        
   $('#video_container').find('iframe').attr('src',URL);
   $('.subcontent-detail').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
   return false;
});
```

Any help/hint is highly welcomed.Thanks in advance.